# How to route certain Drupal page to https?

Tags: drupal

When user open certain page (e.g. `http://example.com/user`), how to config Drupal to route the user to  `https` automatically (i.e. `https://example.com/user`)? Thanks!

Comment: Routing only certain pages over HTTPS is just as secure as no HTTPS at all; since on every pageload a cookie is sent over plain-text. You should at least offer your entire site (most often including all images and assets) over HTTPS for registered users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Secure pages](http://drupal.org/project/securepages) module

Comment: Can you explain? The module page says "This module makes sure that the user is running on a secure page when they create or edit content, view user details, or administer the site." What about other pages? It also says "Make sure that your web server has SSL enabled and your Drupal installation has been configured to support SSL access". If your web server has SSL enabled, doesn't it run SSL on your entire site?

Comment: It's allow secure any page that you will set on admin page.